# Open file 1 and write to 3rd column

Tags: text-processing

I need to open file 1 which has the following format:

```
20336 20336 
20337 20336
20338 20336
20339 20336
20340 20336
20341 20336
.     .
.     .
.     .
71643 20336
71644 20336
71645 20336
71646 20336
```

and create a new file 2 which will have the following format:

```
20336 20336 20301
20337 20336 20301
20338 20336 20304
20339 20336 20304
20340 20336 20307
20341 20336 20307
.     .     .
.     .     .
.     .     .
71643 20336 71643
71644 20336 71643
71645 20336 71645
71646 20336 71645
```

Comment: Unclear: There is no indication of how the third column is calculated.

Comment: to make it more precise I need to write a new column which will start from number 20301 and on second row rewrite 20301 and on next row write 20304 (+3 previous value) and then repeat 20304 and so on until it reaches 71647

Comment: It's a very short awk script. What have you tried? https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I have little experience with awk, any help is greatly appreciated. I simply need to define the number to start from lets say to start from 2 and stop at 14 so the desire pattern is 2 2 5 5 8 8 11 11 14 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ $(NF+1) = 20301 + 3*int((NR-1)/2); print }' file
20336 20336 20301
20337 20336 20301
20338 20336 20304
20339 20336 20304
20340 20336 20307
20341 20336 20307
```

That is, for each input line, create a new field whose value is defined by the formula `20301 + 3*int((NR-1)/2)` where `NR` is the current line number.

Comment: great really appreciate ur help!